# Replacing sections in web.config using web deployment project

Tags: vb.net, web-deployment-project

I am trying to replace the following section to blank section ..

```
 <secureWebPages mode="RemoteOnly" encryptedUri="abc.co.uk" unencryptedUri="www.abc.co.uk" maintainPath="True" warningBypassMode="AlwaysBypass" bypassQueryParamName="BypassSecurityWarning" ignoreHandlers="WithStandardExtensions">
    <files>
        <add path="abc.aspx"/>
    </files>
</secureWebPages>
```

But after executing it is giving me the following error

```
WDP00002: missing section secureWebPages/configuration.
```

Can any one plz help me in this regard

Comment: Is it possible to replace whole configuration section

Comment: +1 I have the same problem, and could use the answer

Answer (score 2):

This error appears to mean the section you wish to replace, cannot be found in the web.config.

For example, my entry in my WDP read

**authentication=authentication.config**

However authentication could not be found in the root, as it is under system.web, so I changed it to

**system.web/authentication=authentication.config**

and this worked.

Note that while debugging this, I tried to replace the whole system.web element, and this did not appear to work either - I am not sure what caused this, but if you cannot replace system.web, I suggest you try a different element, and see if that works, such as connectionStrings

Answer (score 0):

So this problem has popped up for me recently and until finding [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1189124.aspx/1) I was at a loss.
So it seems that the web.config is made up of not only sections, but section groups as well.
Now system.serviceModel, system.web etc are service groups and as such cannot be replaced as a whole.

You can replace sections in the group by using "section group"/"section"=x.config

Hope this helps :)